# ValueError: Expected IDs to be a non-empty list, got [], in Streamlit using ChromaDB, Langchain

Tags: python, openai-api, streamlit, langchain, chromadb

Having error when running the streamlit localport,
**Error:**

```
ValueError: Expected IDs to be a non-empty list, got []
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\FCI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 535, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\FCI\Desktop\Happy Sales AI\OpenAI RAG Chatbot\2nd RAG project\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from utils import *
File "C:\Users\FCI\Desktop\Happy Sales AI\OpenAI RAG Chatbot\2nd RAG project\utils.py", line 43, in <module>
    vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(
File "C:\Users\FCI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\langchain_community\vectorstores\chroma.py", line 778, in from_documents
    return cls.from_texts(
File "C:\Users\FCI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\langchain_community\vectorstores\chroma.py", line 736, in from_texts
    chroma_collection.add_texts(
File "C:\Users\FCI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\langchain_community\vectorstores\chroma.py", line 324, in add_texts
    self._collection.upsert(
File "C:\Users\FCI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\chromadb\api\models\Collection.py", line 477, in upsert
    ) = self._validate_embedding_set(
File "C:\Users\FCI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\chromadb\api\models\Collection.py", line 545, in _validate_embedding_set
    valid_ids = validate_ids(maybe_cast_one_to_many_ids(ids))
File "C:\Users\FCI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\chromadb\api\types.py", line 213, in validate_ids
    raise ValueError(f"Expected IDs to be a non-empty list, got {ids}")
```

Was trying building a streamlit chatbot for my documents. Used Chroma, langchain, streamlit. There are 2 files, main.py file and utils.py file in the same folder. **Please try running it in local**, and use your openai key and pdf files in docs folder.

MAIN.PY FILE CODE:

```
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import ConversationChain
from langchain.chains.conversation.memory import ConversationBufferWindowMemory
from langchain.prompts import (
    SystemMessagePromptTemplate,
    HumanMessagePromptTemplate,
    ChatPromptTemplate,
    MessagesPlaceholder
)
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_chat import message
from utils import *
# from utils import get_conversation_string
# from utils import query_refiner
from utils import find_match


st.subheader("Happy Sales Streamlit")

if 'responses' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['responses'] = ["How can I assist you?"]

if 'requests' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['requests'] = []

llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", openai_api_key="---------")

if 'buffer_memory' not in st.session_state:
            st.session_state['buffer_memory'] = ConversationBufferWindowMemory(k=3, return_messages=True)
            # st.session_state.buffer_memory=ConversationBufferWindowMemory(k=3,return_messages=True)


system_msg_template = SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(template="""Answer the question as truthfully as possible using the provided context, 
and if the answer is not contained within the text below, say 'I don't know'""")


human_msg_template = HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(template="{input}")

prompt_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([system_msg_template, MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history"), human_msg_template])

conversation = ConversationChain(memory=st.session_state.buffer_memory, prompt=prompt_template, llm=llm, verbose=True)

# container for chat history
response_container = st.container()
# container for text box
textcontainer = st.container()

with textcontainer:
    query = st.text_input("Query: ", key="input")
    if query:
        with st.spinner("typing..."):
            conversation_string = get_conversation_string()
            # st.code(conversation_string)
            refined_query = query_refiner(conversation_string, query)
            st.subheader("Refined Query:")
            st.write(refined_query)
            context = find_match(refined_query)
            # print(context)  
            response = conversation.predict(input=f"Context:\n {context} \n\n Query:\n{query}")
        st.session_state.requests.append(query)
        st.session_state.responses.append(response) 
with response_container:
    if st.session_state['responses']:

        for i in range(len(st.session_state['responses'])):
            message(st.session_state['responses'][i],key=str(i))
            if i < len(st.session_state['requests']):
                message(st.session_state["requests"][i], is_user=True,key=str(i)+ '_user')
```

and UTILS.PY file code:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
# import pinecone
import openai

import streamlit as st
openai.api_key = "-------------------------"
model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')

from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFDirectoryLoader
directory = 'Docs'

def load_docs(directory):
  loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader(directory)
  documents = loader.load()
  return documents

documents = load_docs(directory)
print(len(documents))
# //////////////
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

def split_docs(documents,chunk_size=2000,chunk_overlap=20):
  text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=chunk_size, chunk_overlap=chunk_overlap)
  docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
  return docs

docs = split_docs(documents)
print(len(docs))
# //////////////
from langchain_community.embeddings import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
embeddings = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
# //////////////
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
import chromadb
# db = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embeddings)
persist_directory = "chroma_db"

vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(
    documents=docs, embedding=embeddings, persist_directory=persist_directory
)
vectordb.persist()

def find_match(input):
    input_em = model.encode(input).tolist()
    result = vectordb.query(input_em, n_results=2) #includeMetadata=True
    return result['matches'][0]['metadata']['text']+"\n"+result['matches'][1]['metadata']['text']

def query_refiner(conversation, query):

    response = openai.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    prompt=f"Given the following user query and conversation log, formulate a question that would be the most relevant to provide the user with an answer from a knowledge base.\n\nCONVERSATION LOG: \n{conversation}\n\nQuery: {query}\n\nRefined Query:",
    temperature=0.7,
    max_tokens=256,
    top_p=1,
    frequency_penalty=0,
    presence_penalty=0
    )
    return response['choices'][0]['text']

def get_conversation_string():
    conversation_string = ""
    for i in range(len(st.session_state['responses'])-1):
        
        conversation_string += "Human: "+st.session_state['requests'][i] + "\n"
        conversation_string += "Bot: "+ st.session_state['responses'][i+1] + "\n"
    return conversation_string
```

I was trying to build a streamlit AI chatbot using openAI and chromadb(for vector database) for my documents. I got the error "ValueError: Expected IDs to be a non-empty list, got []".

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Answer (score -1):

function call wants IDs list, but not getting any.
#try this in utils.py

```
def load_docs(directory):
loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader(directory)
documents = loader.load()
if not documents:
    raise ValueError(f"No documents loaded from directory: {directory}")
return documents 

documents = load_docs(directory)
print(f"Number of loaded documents: {len(documents)}")
```

#change splits_docs

```
def split_docs(documents, chunk_size=2000, chunk_overlap=20):
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=chunk_size, chunk_overlap=chunk_overlap)
docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
if not docs:
    raise ValueError("Document splitting resulted in an empty list.")
return docs
docs = split_docs(documents)
print(f"Number of document chunks: {len(docs)}")
```

#and check if docs is empty

```
if not docs:
raise ValueError("Cannot initialize Chroma database with an empty document list.")
vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(
documents=docs, embedding=embeddings, persist_directory=persist_directory)
```